# Automate UI Testing in iOS using ionic framework not recognizing text in text boxes for login

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, automation, xcode-instruments

I've exported and compiled an iOS version of an app from the Ionic framework. I'm using Automate UI Testing in iOS's tool instruments. Everything is working fine except for when I use setValue() to fill the login textfield and password textfield. The Boxes are filling with text and when I use the inspect element the values are picked up by the inspector. The problem is when I press login the login and password validations trigger as if there is no text at all in the text boxes. I tried looking all over the net and couldn't find anything relating to my issue. Any help would be much appreciated. I've posted a pic and the code I'm using below.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var scrollView = window.scrollViews()[1];
var webView = scrollView.webViews()[0];
var textField = webView.textFields();
//target.tap({x:28.00, y:28.50});

target.delay(2);

webView.buttons()["LOGIN"].tap();

target.delay(1);

webView.textFields()[0].tap();

target.delay(1);

webView.logElementTree();

webView.textFields()[0].setValue("username");

target.delay(5);

webView.secureTextFields()[0].tap();

target.delay(5);

webView.secureTextFields()[0].setValue("password");

target.delay(5);

webView.buttons()["LOGIN"].tap();
```

[login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Cvd.png)

Comment: Try with setText()

Comment: Tried it, it says that it's not a function.